# React-Redux: mapping an array of objects and initializing a component from each

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a presentational component, , which takes a `{props}` object and populates itself with the proper values.

I also have a container component, , which is supposed to map state to props, take the array of objects representing the plots, map it and initialize a  from each one.

This is throwing me an error-`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`. The "name" in question is a property of the plot.

Looking at the documentation, this error typically happens when we import a component with curly braces when we should import it without, but that's not the case here.

I have a feeling that what is going on is that I am improperly passing the props to the  element, but am not sure of the right way to do it.

Plot.js:

```
import React from 'react';

const Plot = ({ props }) => {
    return (
        <div className="media col-md-4">
            <div className="media-left">
                <a href="#">
                    <img className="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/200/550" alt="Placehold" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <div className="media-body">
                <h4 className="media-heading">{props.name}</h4>
                <ul>
                    <li><strong>Grower: </strong> {props.grower}</li>
                    <li><strong>Region: </strong> {props.region}</li>
                    <li><strong>Current State: </strong> {props.currentState}</li>
                    <li><strong>Next State: </strong> {props.nextState}</li>
                    <li><strong>Days To Next State: </strong> {props.daysToNext}</li>
                    <br />
                    <span class="pull-right">
                        <i id="like1" class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></i> <div id="like1-bs3"></div>
                        <i id="dislike1" class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></i> <div id="dislike1-bs3"></div>
                    </span>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Plot;
```

Dashboard.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../actions';
import Plot from './plot';

class Dashboard extends Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.fetchMessage();
        this.props.fetchPlots();
    }

    render() {
        const plots = this.props.plots;
        return (
            <div>
                <span>{this.props.message}</span>
                <div className='container'>
                        <div className="row">
                            {plots && plots.map((plot) => <Plot key={plot._id} name={plot.name} grower={plot.grower} region={plot.region} currentState={plot.currentState} nextState={plot.nextState} daysToNext={plot.daysToNext}/>)}
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        message: state.auth.message,
        plots: state.auth.plots
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(Dashboard);
```

EDIT:

This is fetchPlots(). I know that it's working and that plots are available as props, because when I add a console.(log) statement before the return statement in dashboard.js, I can see them, and they're fine, with all necessary properties.

```
export function fetchPlots() {
    return function (dispatch) {
        axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}/plots`, {
            headers: {
                authorization: localStorage.getItem('token')
            }
        })
            .then(response => {
                dispatch({
                    type: FETCH_PLOTS,
                    payload: response.data
                });
            });
    }
}
```

My reducer:

```
import {AUTH_USER, UNAUTH_USER, AUTH_ERROR, FETCH_MESSAGE, FETCH_PLOTS} from '../actions/types';

export default function(state={}, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case AUTH_USER:
            return{...state, error:'',authenticated:true};
        case UNAUTH_USER:
            return{...state, authenticated:false};
        case AUTH_ERROR:
            return { ...state, error: action.payload };
        case FETCH_MESSAGE:
            return { ...state, message: action.payload }
        case FETCH_PLOTS:
            return { ...state, plots: action.payload }
    }
    return state;
```

Comment: You should do your async in `componentDidMount()`. Please check and let us know if it helps. Btw can you paste your `fetchMessage()` and `fetchPlots()` snippets

Comment: @hawk you mean that I should call fetchMessage() and fetchPlots() in componentDidMount? I have checked, and the outputs of both are available in render(), they're properly being stored in state and retrieved from state with mapStateToProps. The message renders fine.

Comment: you only want to fetch your data once. componentDidMount gets called once. render gets called multiple times.

Comment: @BorisK Most likely problem is in action dispatching, can you share action handler with us

Comment: @hawk do you mean the reducer?

Comment: @BorisK yes a mean reducer

Comment: @SamPakvis I am calling the async actions in componentWillMount()-this only gets called once, correct?

Comment: @hawk added it. I do not think the problem is with the reducer, since all the other actions are working fine, including async ones, and since I can see the plot data from the async call showing up in state and props in dashboard.js.

Comment: @SamPakvis checked, and calling the async actions in componentDidMount() doesn't change anything-same behavior, same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `const Plot = ({ props })` into `const Plot = (props)`

Comment: Nice, that did it! But why? What is the actual difference?

Comment: @BorisK You was trying to destruct props object and retrive `props.props` `{ props }` means destructuring [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: @BorisK `const Plot = ({ name })` this will also work

Answer (score 1):

You are making an ajax call to get the data. So the ajax call takes some time to execute. Because of which `this.props.plots` would be undefined. So you need to make a null check in your `Dashboard` component

```
render() {
    const plots = this.props.plots;
    if(plots === undefined){
        return <div>Loading ...</div>
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <span>{this.props.message}</span>
            <div className='container'>
                    <div className="row">
                        {plots && plots.map((plot) => <Plot key={plot._id} name={plot.name} grower={plot.grower} region={plot.region} currentState={plot.currentState} nextState={plot.nextState} daysToNext={plot.daysToNext}/>)}
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Once the ajax call is finished the render function will be called again then the else condition will be followed and then it will not give the error you are getting.

Also make your api calls from `componentDidMount()` so that it's not called every time the state changes.

Comment: error is different with solution you provided. Also plots is properly checked before its accessed

Comment: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

Comment: @ShubhamJain while this is a cool way to avoid having to add more actions/reducers, what happens is that when it finishes loading, I get the same error: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

Comment: Any file name or line number it shows where it's getting error? @BorisK

Comment: @ShubhamJain the extended error is this: `bundle.js:41937 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at new Plot (http://localhost:8080/bundle.js:41937:23)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (http://localhost:8080/bundle.js:7386:19)`

Comment: @BorisK could you log props in Plot component and see what it prints?

Comment: @ShubhamJain "undefined". So it does appear to be an issue of passing props correctly.

Comment: Yes and now console log the props you are sending inside of your dashboard component and see what are you sending.

Comment: @ShubhamJain got it! Hawk was right-it was the way I was accessing props in the <plot /> component!